# Way to provide same argument to multiple %@ in format string?

Tags: objective-c, string-formatting

Say I have a bit of code:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT %@ FROM %@ ORDER BY %@", columnName, tableName, columnName];
```

Is there any way to specify that I want `columnName` to go to *both* the first and third `%@`s? That's just an example. I'm curious to see if there's any possible combination, really.

Comment: Anyone using string formats should have a bookmark to the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT %1$@ FROM %2$@ ORDER BY %1$@", columnName, tableName];
```

(Note that this is not specific to `NSString`: in POSIX, you can do this with any of the `printf()` family of functions.)

Comment: Wow, thanks! That was crazy fast. Apparently, NSPredicate is not part of that family, since that's throwing an 'Unable to parse the format string' exception.

Comment: @ele I didn't claim you could do that with `NSPredicate` either... You wanted to format a string, I showed you how to format a string.

Comment: Oh, it wasn't a complaint. I'm sorry if it came off that way.

Comment: @ele No problem, just saying! I didn't want to sound mean.